# Problems filtering image with prewitt

Tags: matlab, filters, image-processing, convolution, correlation

I'm trying to filter an image vertically to get the edges, in MATLAB, but I get very different results from convultion and correlation.

CODE:

```
vf = fspecial('prewitt');

iyconv = imfilter(im, vf, 'replicate', 'conv');
iycorr = imfilter(im, vf, 'replicate', 'corr');
```

result in the image below,

[image]

why does the convultion only outputs the lower part of the mouth, and on contrary the correlation teh upper?

Comment: Your assumption that only upper or lower parts are returned is not true. Once the upper parts are returned positive and the lower negative and the other once the reversed is the case. If you would apply some abs operator, both result images would look the same.

Answer (score 1):

Prewitt kernel is rotated 180 degree between correlation and convolution.

You can check this link: http://www.equalis.com/blogpost/731635/129540/Convolution-and-Correlation-in-Image-Processing